# $\mu(A \cap I) \le a \mu(I)$ implies $\mu(A) = 0$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $\mu$ be lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, $0<a<1$. If $\mu(A \cap I) \le a \mu(I)$ holds for any interval $I$, can I say $\mu(A)=0$?

I tried to construct a counterexample by considering something similar to cantor set but failed. Can anyone give some comments? Thanks!

Comment: What if $A$ and $I$ are disjoint?

Comment: @KyleGannon sorry was a typo. the inequality should be $\mu(A \cap I) \le \mu(I)$

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/933233/prove-borel-measurable-set-a-with-the-following-property-has-measure-0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint.** By the [Lebesgue density theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_density_theorem), for a.e. $x \in \Bbb{R}$ we have

$$ \mathbf{1}_A (x) = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{\mu(A \cap [x,x+h])}{\mu([x,x+h])}. $$

What can you conclude about the indicator function $\mathbf{1}_A$?

Answer (score 6):

Suppose first $m(A) \subset [-R,R]$ for some $R>0.$ If $A \subset I_1 \cup I_2 \cup \cdots,$ where the $I_n$ are pairwise disjoint open intervals, then

$$\tag 1  m(A) = m(A\cap (\cup I_n))= m(\cup (A\cap I_n)) = \sum m(A\cap I_n) \le \sum am(I_n) = a\sum m(I_n).$$

Now the infimum of $\sum m(I_n)$ over all such converings of $A$ equals $m(A).$ Thus $(1)$ implies $m(A) \le a m(A).$ Because $m(A) < \infty,$ we must have $m(A) = 0.$

If $A$ is unbounded, then we can write $A = \cup_n\  A\cap [-n,n].$ Apply the above for each fixed $n$ to see each $m(A\cap [-n,n]) =0.$ Hence $m(A) = 0.$